# Natty broke my system! I think I know how to fix it but

Tags: 11.04, system

I've just upgraded to Natty, having patiently waited for the final release date and for Ubuntu to nag me about it every minute. Now, **whenever I log into anything other than Ubuntu Safe Mode, the system hangs**. The mouse doesn't work, the clock freezes, the ssh connexion is broken. **This happens AFTER THE LOGIN**, on ALL desktops, except for safe mode, including Unity, Classic and, my standard desktop, KDE.

**I can't find any error in any log.** All seems to work fine. Sometimes the system starts for a couple of seconds and then freezes, sometimes it freezes while the desktop is still loading. But the computer is completely unusable outside of the safe mode.

I'm thinking, if there is **a list** somewhere **of what Safe Mode does NOT start**, I could start all of these things one by one and see what makes my system freeze that way. Is there such a list somewhere?

Or even better: does anyone have an idea of what it might be? **The problem does not come from the 3D or Compiz** or anything of the kind. That works. I've tried it and disabled it from KDE. Plus, "Classic no effects" has the same problem as the rest.

What could it be? And what does Classic Safe Mode not do?

Thanks.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Most desktop environments load the .desktop files in `~/config/autostart`. I try moving all of those files to another folder and seeing if the desktop environments load. If not, then I'm not sure what else is shared between all the DE's that would make then crash the whole system.